# Can I migrate this question to Mathoverflow?

Tags: support, migration, math-stackexchange

I asked the question

["Which sets occur as boundaries of other sets in topological spaces?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845018/which-sets-occur-as-boundaries-of-other-sets-in-topological-spaces)

on MathStackExchange on June 23, thinking that the answer is probably known, but there are no answers yet. Is this sufficient reason to ask it again on Mathoverflow? Am I likely to get answers then?

Comment: It seems you got an answer. Now, you might not be satisfied with the answer, but this can also mean that the questions was not quite clear.

Comment: @quid No, there are no answers yet, only a comment (and some other deleted comments, now integrated into the question).

Comment: I meant the partial answer given in a comment.

Comment: Seems like this meta question has provoked another helpful comment - maybe not necessary.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Irrespective of whether it’s appropriate to move the question to MO, it is appropriate and on-topic to inquire about it here on meta.

Comment: The comment I made on MSO implies that spaces with the required property must be perfect. I think one can show that this is also sufficient for $T_0$ second-countable spaces (that is, if $X$ is $T_0$ second-countable, then every closed subset of $X'$ is a boundary of a subset of $X$, even one with an empty interior). However, it seems to me that the question may be rather nontrivial in full generality, and that it is fine to re-ask it on MO.

Comment: @Emil Good point.  I agree the question looks fine for MO, preferably with a link here.

Comment: I think that @EmilJeřábek comment shows that a *revised* version of the question would be fine. Why not instead of migrating it ask a question taking the information obtained via comment(answers) into account, linking to oiriginal and the meta question. Or if you really want to migrate it, edit it beforehand.

Comment: @quid, EmilJerabek, Carl Thanks for the responses, I am reposting it here on MO.

Comment: @quid By the way, by migrating I have always meant just copying the post manually and reposting, with revisions. Is there another way of making that happen?

Comment: Yes. In fact "migration" is a particular technical term in the Stack Exchange network. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work